# Read more redirection problem

Tags: wp-query

I have tried

```
<?global $more;
$more = 0;?>
```

On pages and read more link shows but the full content is not shown. If I click read more it remains on same page. Logically I'm supposed to taken to `index.php`, but why not?

Comment: Where are you using this code?

Comment: What theme are you using? What other code there is where you expect content to be output?